# Adding new info in Address Book iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, addressbook

How can I add an address to a Address Book contact in iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

Well, in order to search/view the Apple developer iOS reference you will need to join (for free).

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html

Its a decent resource, and it shows you examples (most of the time).

Comment: Another useful resource is the Address Book Programming Guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1